# Extension Problem Related to the Product Measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

This is Exercise 9 from Tao's note on probability.

https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/275a-notes-2-product-measures-and-independence/comment-page-2/#comment-681889

Let ${(\Omega_i, {\mathcal F}_i)_{i \in A}}$ be a collection of measurable spaces. For each finite ${B \subset A}$, let ${\mu_B}$ be a probability measure on ${(\Omega_B, {\mathcal F}_B)} = (\prod_{i \in B}\Omega_i, \prod_{i \in B}\mathcal{F}_i)$ obeying the compatibility condition

$\displaystyle  \mu_B( \pi_{B \rightarrow C}^{-1}(E_C) ) = \mu_C(E_C) \ \ \ \ \ (6)$

for all finite ${C \subset B \subset A}$ and ${E_C \in {\mathcal F}_C}$, where ${\pi_{B \rightarrow C}: \Omega_B \rightarrow \Omega_C}$ is the obvious restriction. Can one then define a probability measure ${\mu_A}$ on ${(\Omega_A, {\mathcal F}_A)}$ such that

$\displaystyle  \mu_A( \pi_{B}^{-1}(E_B) ) = \mu_B(E_B) \ \ \ \ \ (7)$

for all finite ${B \subset A}$ and ${E_B \subset {\mathcal F}_B}$?

**Question:** Show that for any ${(\Omega_i, {\mathcal F}_i)_{i \in A}}$ and ${\mu_B}$ for finite ${B \subset A}$ as in the above extension problem, there is at most one probability measure ${\mu_A}$ with the stated properties.

Tao stated that the compatibility condition is not, strictly speaking, needed for the uniqueness aspect for the extension problem, but it is needed for existence. My idea is then to show that if there exist two such measures $\mu_A$ and $\mu'_A$, then the collection $\mathcal{F}$ of sets on which $\mu_A$ and $\mu’_A$ agree is a monotone class containing the elementary sets (sets of the form $\pi_{B}^{-1}(E_B)$ for some finite $B \subset A$), and hence is the entire $\mathcal{F}_A = \prod_{i \in A} \mathcal{F}_i$ by the monotone class lemma. Is this the correct way to think about it?

Comment: The monotone class lemma probably works, but the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem also works. Once you find a $\pi$-system that generates $\mathcal{F}_A$ on which $\mu$_A and $\mu$_B agree, the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem implies that they agree on all of $\mathcal{F}_A$. Here the $\pi$-system would be all "finite products" of measurable sets.